# Can we reject our own edit?

Tags: feature-request, editing, suggested-edits

After editing something, I realized that I had done something incorrectly. There should be a way users can remove or edit their edit suggestions.

Comment: Similar older question, but with no answers: [Undo edits just suggested](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4969/undo-edits-just-suggested). And there is also a feature request on meta.SE: [How can I cancel an edit I made on another user's question or answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80933/how-can-i-cancel-an-edit-i-made-on-another-users-question-or-answer)